# get_timelines doesn't return 3,200 latest tweets

Tags: r, rtweet

I am currently using rtweet to gather the timelines of a number of German politicians. While doing so, I ran into the problem that while for some (with more than 3,200 tweets) I was able to gather the full number of the 3,200 most recent tweets, while for others running the code only returns slightly less than 3,200.

Did you already run into this problem and do you know what causes it? Here is one example of a politician for which I can only gather the last 3187 statuses:

`test <- get_timeline("wanderwitz", n=3200)`

While for others the code works fine, such as:

```
test <- get_timeline("berlinliebich", n=3200)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suspect it has to do with deleted tweets, and that the API is pulling the last 3,200 statuses that ever existed, but only 3,187 (99.6%) are still available.

Comment: @JonSpring: Thank you!